# set tags vlaue in viewpage using web api for update purpose in angular

Tags: angular

i am using `mat-chips` in add tags page ....i am using web api for view tags in node... i want to show dynamic tags inside that particular mat-chips fields using formcontrol in edit page...
it show `[object object][object object]` in that mat-chips filed.... how to show particular tag value inside that field

this is my response for tags:

```
 {
"Code": "1",
"Message": "Success",
"Data": {
    "medicineuses": [
        {
            "uses": "Fever"
        },
        {
            "uses": "HeadAche"
        }
      ]
       }
   }
```

this is my html :

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let uses of addUses;let indx=index;" [selectable]="selectable" (removed)="remove(uses)">
         {{uses.name}}
          <button matChipRemove>
            <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-chip>
```

this is my component:

```
           ngOnInit(): void {
             this.medicineService.viewMedicine(this.router.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(
             (result)=>{
             console.log(result);
              this.editmedicineForm=new FormGroup({
       
           medicineuses: new FormControl(result.Data['medicineuses']),
       
           })
         });

       }
```

this is my output:
[image: this is my view page]

how to get array of values inside mat-chips like a tag....

Comment: medicineuses is a array type, so you need formArray instead of formControl

Comment: this.editmedicineForm=new FormGroup({   medicineuses: new FormArray(result.Data['medicineuses']),   }) ... but there is no tag ..it is empty

Comment: @GRD i put above code but there is no data..that field is empty

Comment: `medicineuses: new FormControl(result.Data['medicineuses'][0]),` Do change like this